# How to solve for $x$ in an equation such as "$2x^2 - 5x + 64\log(x) + 776 = 0$"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to find the shortest distance between a point and a logarithmic line. So far I've applied the distance formula, found the derivative of the distance equation and made it equal to zero. That's how I got the equation in the title: $$2x^2 - 5x + 64\log(x) + 776 = 0.$$ From this point I haven't been able to figure out how to solve for $x$. So the question is, how to I solve for $x$ in this equation?

Comment: I’m pretty sure that many of these types of equations can not be solved algebraically. This isn’t to say that your solution does not have one, just to say it is not guaranteed to have one.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer.

Comment: I am writing an answer that suggests how we can analytically find a root. Should I post it?

Comment: You will need a numerical method, e.g. Newton -Raphson method

Comment: We find $$x\approx  5.42225066756636430174*10^{-6}$$

Comment: Yes  @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг please post it.

Comment: x=$10^\frac{-776}{64}$ will also be extremely close to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that it is impossible to solve for the equation algebraically. Let $f(x) = 2x^2 - 5x +64\log x+776$. We are trying to find when $f(x) = 0$. Note that the domain of $f$ is $(0,\infty)$ because of the logarithm( which I assume is the natural logarithm i.e. to the base $e$).

Going for it analytically, first we note that the derivative is $f' = 4x + \frac{64}{x} - 5 = \frac{4x^2 - 5x+64}{x}$ which  is strictly positive on $(0,\infty)$ since the numerator has discriminant negative , hence is always positive, while the denominator is always positive.

Also, from the fact that $f(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to 0^+$ and $f(1) >0$, we see that any root is between $0$ and $1$.

We can actually do better : note that if $x = e^y$, where $y < 0$ since we now want $0<x<1$, then we have : $$2x^2 - 5x = 2(x^2 - 2.5x) = 2((x-1.25)^2) - \frac{25}{8}$$

Therefore, we see that on $[0,1]$ that this part is between $0$ and $-3$.

So if equality holds, then in particular, $64y + 776$ is between $0$ and $3$, so we get $\frac{-776}{64} \leq y \leq \frac{-773}{64}$, which after exponentiation gives $ 5.422\leq 10^6x \leq 5.682$. At least we get the number of significant zeros and the first significant non-zero digit, using at most two exponential operations.

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation!

Comment: You are welcome! Since you are new, up vote any answers you like, and accept the best answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 1):

first the derivation of this equation is greater than zero

$y=2x^2-5x+64\log(x)+776$ so $\frac{dy}{dx}=4x-5+\frac{64}{x}=\frac{4x^2-5x+64}{x}$  in $4x^2-5x+64\geq 0$ since $\Delta \leq 0$ so always $\frac{dy}{dx}>0$

also $y(0^{+})=-\infty$ and there are some $y\geq 0$ so you have a one root and no more. (since $y$ is increasing and exist $a$ and $b$ such that $f(a)f(b)<0$و Intermediate value theorem)

R code

```
    y<-function(x){
    2*x^2-5*x+64*log(x)+776
      }
    uniroot(y,c(5.414414e-06,5.423423e-06))
   $root
   [1] 5.423423e-06

   $f.root
    [1] 0.01383579

   $iter
      [1] 0

   $init.it
   [1] NA

   $estim.prec
  [1] 9.009e-09
```

so you sure have a unique answer

Comment: better answer use  uniroot(y,lower =5.1e-06 , upper = 5.6e-06,tol=10^(-30))